# Is there any opinion suggesting Jews returning from warfare should cleanse themselves in the mikvah to purify from combat?

Tags: sin, mikvah-ritual-bath, army-military-war

We are taught that because King David had spilled the blood of the Canaanites in his conquest of Haaretz Yisrael, he was forbidden from building the Beit Hamikdash. This responsibility fell unto Solomon who was not tainted by warfare.

This led me to the thought of warfare in general and how such things may taint you, not only literally but even spiritually, for the acts you may be forced to take.

Is there any opinion by modern or historical Rabbinnum which suggests a returning soldier should immediately submerge in mikvah to purify themselves of combat? I would imagine it may hold some value even if it has never been directly discussed.

Comment: Consider Numbers 31:21